# Listen for click on div, but not when any of its children are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to hide a div and its children when the div is clicked, but not when any event occurs to any of its children; such as, swipe, tap, or click.

The jQuery that hides the div on click is simple:

```
$("#tabs").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

But I've noticed that when it's children are clicked or swiped, the div fades out.

How can I prevent the div from fading out when those events occur on its children, but allow it to fade `onclick` of only itself?

Comment: if the children has an event handler as well you could always prevent the event bubbling for the children. But this method is only good when there is only 1 children per div

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if the element clicked is the same element that was bound:

```
$("#tabs").click(function(e){
    if (e.target == this)
        $(this).fadeOut();
});
```